# 'Object is not extensible' error when attempting to write to Google Firestore database

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to play around with my Firebase Firestore database, and add a few initial items, but I haven't been able to get past this error:

> Error adding document:  TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

Here is the function that I created to make the request:

```
  async addUser(
    user: UserCredential,
    displayName: string
  ): Promise<Observable<CreateUserResponse>> {
    try {
      const userData = {
        displayName,
      };
      await setDoc(doc(this.firestore, 'users', user.user.uid), {
        ...userData,
      });
      console.log('Document written with ID: ', user.user.uid);
      return observableOf({ response: user, displayName });
    } catch (exception) {
      console.error('Error adding document: ', exception);
      return observableOf({ response: DEFAULT_DATABASE_ERROR, displayName });
    }
  }
```

I've tried adding a console.log statement before the request is made to check the value of `this.firestore`, and it appears to be well configured with data from `this.app` (includes those fields within the object).

This error isn't very descriptive, which adds to my confusion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have u tried using `await setDoc(doc(this.firestore, 'users', user.user.uid), userData);` or `await setDoc(doc(this.firestore, 'users', user.user.uid), Object.assign({}, userData));` instead of `await setDoc(doc(this.firestore, 'users', user.user.uid), {...userData, };`?

Comment: I suspect the error message comes from this line instead: `observableOf({ response: user, displayName })`, so you might want to validate that first.

Comment: @DVN-Anakin I have tried both of those, yes

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My `console.log('Document..` line is never hit, so it doesn't seem like that's the source